# Opencart Htaccess redirection with an Index path does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, indexing, opencart-3

OpenCart 3.0.3.3 theme Ultrastore and Ocfilter

I'm trying to configure htaccess redirection to http://test.podarok-kamni.ru/

Problem with the INDEX

This is how redirection works - INDX

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=indx.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-nefrita? [R=301,L]
```

But this is how redirection does not work - INDEX

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa? [R=301,L]
```

Please tell me what the problem may be , what to configure ?
With Respect

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

php_value upload_max_filesize 512M

php_value post_max_size 512M

php_flag display_errors on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=indx.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-nefrita? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you please share some example URLs that are not working ?

Comment: http://test.podarok-kamni.ru/index.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html it should open http://test.podarok-kamni.ru/derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa - it`s not working. 

http://test.podarok-kamni.ru/indx.php/cat/c706_Derevo-schastya.html
the redirect works correctly to  http://test.podarok-kamni.ru/derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-nefrita

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]


#  index.php/cat/c1398_Nasekomye.html - kulony-i-podveski/kulony-iz-yantarya-v-bronze-nasekomye
RewriteRule ^index.php/cat/c1398_Nasekomye.html$ derevja-schastja/derevya-schastya-iz-geliotropa1? [R=301,L]

# index.php?cat=1422 - kulony-i-podveski/kulony-poludragocennye-forma-obrabotannaya-biryuza
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=1422$
RewriteRule index.php$ kulony-i-podveski/kulony-poludragocennye-forma-obrabotannaya-biryuza? [R=301,L]
```